# difference in csv.reader and pandas - python

Tags: python, pandas

I am importing a csv file using csv.reader and pandas. However, the number of rows from the same file are different.

```
reviews = []
openfile = open("reviews.csv", 'rb')
r = csv.reader(openfile)
for i in r:
    reviews.append(i)
openfile.close()
print len(reviews)
```

the results is 10,000 (which is the correct value). However, pandas returns a different value.

```
df = pd.read_csv("reviews.csv", header=None)
df.info()
```

this returns 9,985

Does anyone know why there is difference between the two methods of importing data?

I just tried this:

```
reviews_df = pd.DataFrame(reviews)
reviews_df.info()
```

This returns 10,000.

Comment: I can not reproduce this problem. When I run this code on a `csv` file the difference is only one row and that's the `header`

Comment: Can you give us a small sample input file which demonstrates the problem?  This should be possible if you first figure out *which* rows are missing.

Comment: That is supposed to be. I have never seen this issue before.

Comment: Is there a way to figure out which rows are missing? That knowledge would be helpful at this point.

Comment: @kevin: Sure, you could write the table back out to a new CSV and diff them.

Comment: @John Zwinck That makes sense. Thanks. I will try and report here.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Thanks for your suggestion. I was able to find some empty rows.

Comment: @kevin: Meaning the rows were blank lines?  Yeah, that might do it.  You could post your own answer to your question to resolve this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Refer to the [`pandas.read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) there is an argument named `skip_blank_lines` and its default value is `True` hence unless you are setting it to `False` it will not read the blank lines.

> **Consider the following example, there are two blank rows:**
>
> ```
> A,B,C,D
> 0.07,-0.71,1.42,-0.37
>
> 0.08,0.36,0.99,0.11
> 1.06,1.55,-0.93,-0.90
> -0.33,0.13,-0.11,0.89
> 1.91,-0.74,0.69,0.83
> -0.28,0.14,1.28,-0.40
> 0.35,1.75,-1.10,1.23
>
> -0.09,0.32,0.91,-0.08
> ```
>
> **Read it with skip_blank_lines=False:**
>
> ```
> df = pd.read_csv('test_data.csv', skip_blank_lines=False)
> len(df)
> 10
> ```
>
> **Read it with skip_blank_lines=True:**
>
> ```
>   df = pd.read_csv('test_data.csv', skip_blank_lines=True)
>   len(df)
>   8
> ```